# Zombie CADisplayLink?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Is it possible that a CADisplayLink gets called one or two more times even after being invalidated?
It looks that way to me, and this is causing me a problem because the target object is called where it's already gone so it crashes.
Thanks!

Comment: I have been experiencing the same issue. The problem here is that I'm trying to invalidate the CADisplayLink in order to deallocate a temporal object that is not the CADisplayLink target, but it's used by the target. We need a method of knowing when the CADisplayLink has been truly halted.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, "The newly constructed display link retains the target." so it shouldn't crash in any case.

**EDIT:** Try setting the environment variables [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)=YES and NSDeallocateZombies=NO (the latter is the default, apparently), which may help debug the crash.